# the inner select field cannot have more than one relationship in SOQL

Tags: soql

I have a relationship like below and i get an error like - **the inner select field Customer_r cannot have more than one relationship.**

I want to find customers where products are having customer id and belongs to the books category.

**Customers_c**

- id
- name
- Country

**Products**

- id,
- name
- category
- Customer_r --> id, name

I tried with the below query but not worked.

`SELECT id, name from Customers_c WHERE id IN (SELECT Customer_r.id FROM Products WHERE Customer_r .id != NULL AND category = 'BOOKS')`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `__r.Id`, use `__c` instead.

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Customer__c FROM Products WHERE Category = 'Books')
```

There's no need to filter out null values, as this happens automatically when filtering on Id.

In general, you should use `__c` when you want the Id from a lookup field.